# Remove a section of a list using lists in Python

Tags: python

I have two lists, `l1` and `l2`. `l1` is a list of many numbers separated by commas. `l2` has a section of `l1`.

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
l2 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

I want `l1` to become `l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` by directly removing `l2` from `l1`

Can I do that without `While XXX:`, `For I in XXX:`, and Recursions?

Comment: Will there ever be repeats, and if so, do you want to preserve duplicates?

Comment: Why don't you want to iterate or use recursion?

Comment: Related: [Subtracting two lists in Python](/q/2070643/4518341). If order is unimportant, then it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

You can if you convert the lists into sets.  You can also use list comprehension.

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
l2 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

# using sets and the difference operator
l3 = list(set(l1) - set(l2))

# or using list comprehension
l3 = [i for i in l1 if i not in l2]
```

There is also the builtin function `filter` and the itertools version `filterfalse`, these are not as preferred since they are less readable however

```
l3 = list(filter(lambda x: x not in l2, l1))

import itertools

l3 = list(itertools.filterfalse(lambda x: x in l2, l1))
```

Comment: It's worth noting that using `set`s isn't guaranteed to preserve order. In this example, order just happens to be preserved when I run it, but I think it's a quirk of the CPython implementation. If I swap the ints for strs, order is not preserved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple line of code to do that

```
b2 = list(filter(lambda num: num not in l2, l1))
```

You need to know the filter function iterate over the array.

Comment: Don't use `list(filter(lambda))`. It's much more readable to use a list comprehension. See [Alexander's answer](/a/73438864/4518341).